# Does Linux have mount limit for device/hardware?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I noticed for general USB storage device, as long as I have enough USB end points. The Kernel will recognize the device.

Another example is I noticed when I mount two cdc-acm devices(USB modem) on a board, the Kernel only recognized one of them.
And when I configured the Kernel, there's no option for the number of the device I can mount, but only the option to turn it on/off.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] in each site has information regarding the topics that are appropriate on that site.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.